# List index out of range on the Django App while running the development server

Tags: python, django, django-views

I just got a new job working for a website and I am trying to get a development server working on my work computer. I've copied all the configurations and what not and I am still getting errors.

When I try to display the front page I get

```
list index out of range
```

The exception is being raised

```
python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py in __getitem__, line 190
```

Here is the traceback information.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'south',
 'radio.frontend',
 'radio.events',
 'radio.library',
 'radio.logs',
 'radio.station',
 'radio.staff',
 'gravatar',
 'djcelery',
 'gunicorn']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/wluw/wluw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/wluw/wluw/wluw/radio/frontend/views.py" in home
  20.     schedule = Schedule.objects.get_current_schedule(now)
File "/home/wluw/wluw/wluw/radio/station/managers.py" in get_current_schedule
  64.         return results[0]
File "/home/wluw/wluw/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in __getitem__
  190.             return list(qs)[0]

Exception Type: IndexError at /
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Here is some of the code I've got that is adding to the error

```
class ScheduleManager(models.Manager):
    def get_current_schedule(self, when):
        results = self.filter(start_date__lte=when, end_date__gte=when).order_by('-start_date')
        #try:
        #if(results[0]):
        return results[0]
        #else:
           # return "null"
        #
        #except IndexError:
            #raise self.model.DoesNotExist

    def get_current_schedule_or_404(self, when):
        try:
            return self.get_current_schedule(when)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

I am still not to familiar with python so any suggestions of where to fiddle around with the code would be great.
I have a feeling it has something to do with database not being populated with data, but I added in stuff and I still get the error.

Thanks for any help you may give.

If you need more info just let me know.

Comment: Did you try checking that `results` actually *contains anything*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traceback tells you what the problem is. The homepage is trying to display the top Schedule - but you don't have any in your database. You need to create some.

Comment: I can't believe I over looked that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it locally in different ways?

I have seen my Django code react differently in different server environs (e.g. mod_wsgi vs gunicorn vs `manage.py runserver` vs werkzeug... etc). It won't hurt to try a few different codepaths in that respect.

Also, a good sanity check are management commands like `manage.py validate` and `manage.py shell` -- I lean on the latter quite a bit when building doctests (which if you're new to python, you'll find out about doctests very soon I would wager).

Best of luck.

Comment: What type of things should I be doing in the shell? Just trying to use the models I've created and what not?

Comment: Yeah -- if you don't have a comprehensive suite of unit-tests on hand (which is how most people incl. myself usually start projects) the shell will let you check your modules in isolation. Relatedly, whenever possible, I define my view function signatures like so: `def someview(request=None, [...])` -- that way, the `someview` function can be imported and tested w/o having to mock up a fake request object. Things like that will help you track down the bug.

Comment: Also, install this if you can: http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/RunServerPlus -- the werkzeug debugger will let you inspect tracebacks like this with an AJAX debugger that offers you incredible forensic detail.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the info. It kind of sucks for me because I wasn't the one who wrote the code. I am getting a 500 error for that link, so I must look elsewhere for it. I'm going to fiddle around with the shell for now and see if I can get any more info.

Comment: No problem -- these are the fundaments of my own forensic code-editing suite, which I have amassed while dealing with other peoples' buggy code, myself. it's a dity world, good luck w/ it.